# How do I get setTimeout to read the value from the INPUT?

Tags: javascript

```
  <input type="number" id="number">
  <button onlcick="countdown()">COUNTDOWN</button>
```

```
  var t = document.getElementById('number').value;
function countdown() {
    setTimeout(function(){alert("hi!");}, t);
}
</script>
```

I want `setTimeout` to get variable `t`. Variable `t` will get whatever 4 digit number is in the `input` tag & when your press the button, it will start subtracting. However, when I try press the button it does not do this.
Is there something wrong with the code? Or, is this not how you do it?

Comment: _" it will start subtracting"_ What will start subtracting?

Comment: What ever the value for the `input` tag is.

Comment: Whatever the value is in the INPUT TAG

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have 2 mistakes, first change `onlcick` to `onclick`, and add `t` variable to function `countdown` because you need get value after click, but in your example variable will be empty

```
function countdown() {
    var t = document.getElementById('number').value;
    setTimeout(function(){alert("hi!");}, t);
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/drcnwf2r/)

Also you can clear timeout in order to start new timer after click, like so

```
var timer;
function countdown() {
    var t = document.getElementById('number').value;
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(function(){alert("hi!");}, t);
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/drcnwf2r/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Main problem: you need to read input value inside of the function when it's called:

```
function countdown() {
    var t = document.getElementById('number').value;
    setTimeout(function(){alert("hi!");}, t);
}
```

The variable `t` is initialized on page load and will not update automatically when input value changes. This is your responsibility to read new value from input.

And another thing (which is probably just a typo) but yes, attribute should be `onclick`.

Answer (score 1):

It appears you have a typo in your button it should be `<button onclick="countdown()">COUNTDOWN</button>`

Answer (score 1):

Define pointer for timeout

```
window.hTimeOut = null;
function countdown() {
```

reset previously called and not finished countdown (timeout)

```
    if(window.hTimeOut!=null) clearTimeout(window.hTimeOut);
```

create new timeout

```
    window.hTimeOut = setTimeout(function(){
            alert("hi!");
```

reset timeout pointer after it finished

```
            window.hTimeOut!=null;
```

and pass new value of time into it

```
    }, document.getElementById('number').value);
}
```

Comment: It is generally helpful to also include some explanation of what you have changed in addition to a block of code.